# Wrong default password during installation Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: password, raspberrypi

I get an incorrect password error during installation of Ubuntu 19.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4. When I use username `ubuntu` and `ubuntu` as password, I get incorrect password.

I get this error during the installation. So when I want to fill in the password `ubuntu` during the installation I get the error:

> Incorrect login.

What can I do?

Comment: You will have to work out the details a bit to clarify your question. You successfully installed Ubuntu, but now you cannot log in?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't successfully installed Ubuntu. I get this error during the installation. So when I want to fill in the password ubuntu during the installation I get the error: Incorrect login.

Comment: The needed information belongs to your question. Please *edit*.

Comment: There is no "default password" when you initially install Ubuntu. What image are you trying to install?

Comment: Did you try username: pi and password: raspberry ?

Comment: This is a bug in Canonical's Ubuntu pi install docs. The docs say to use "ubuntu" for initial login username and password but this does not work the first time the prompt is shown. The first time it is displayed in yellow and you will not be able to login. If you reboot the prompt will turn white and then the "ubuntu" username and password will work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

The login prompt appears before setup is totally complete.

If you wait a few minutes some more text will appear on the console. After this the default credentials will work:

- Username: `ubuntu`
- Password: `ubuntu`

The default credentials are specified [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server). At the time of writing the text is as follows:

```
When prompted to log in, use "ubuntu" for the username and the password. You will be asked to change this default password after you log in.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hold `Shift` when booting, you will get to GRUB.
Go down to Advanced Options, and select the `root` option from the Recovery menu.. That will drop you to the root shell.

Unmount your filesystem with `mount -o remount,rw /`, then type in `passwd <username>` (where `<username>` is, well, your username). You will be prompted for a new password. Once done, you may restart!